# How to place a shape in text?

Tags: svg

**Is there a way to integrate a shape (e.g. a `<rect>`) in an SVG text as if it were a character?**

It should look something like this (with a simple rectangle in this example, but possibly arbitrary other graphics in the actual application):

[image: example graphic]

In other words, essentially like the common functionality found in text editors (such as MS Word or OpenOffice Writer) to anchor an image in the text flow rather than at an absolute position.

Ideally, the markup should be as straightforard as this (pseudo-code):

```
<text><tspan>Hello, </tspan><rect width="10px" height="10px" fill="blue"/><tspan>World!</tspan></text>
```

However, according to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html), it is not possible to add shape elements directly as children of either `<text>` or `<tspan>`. `<altGlyph>` sounds like it *might* be a solution, but I failed to find out how to use it, and examples for that element are extremely sparse.

Comment: put the rect in a pattern and apply the pattern as a fill to the text.

Comment: @RobertLongson: But then, the *text* will be filled, right? Not its background, but the character themselves.

Comment: Perhaps you meant this: https://www.w3.org/2013/10/SVG_in_OpenType/

Comment: @RobertLongson: I have added a graphic and some pseudo-code to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: That's SVG in opentype then. Firefox supports it.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Maybe that's a solution - but I'm not sure I understand how to use it. It seems like it's primarily meant as a way to define graphics as reusable characters, whereas I'm only looking for inserting a graphic at a particular location in a given text, one time.

Comment: use the SVG DOM to get character positions and place the rect wherever you want to then.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Well, that sounds ... rather "untidy". The rect will not truly be "in" the text, I'd have to manually adjust the text to provide the appropriate clear space in between, and when moving the text, I'd have to also move the rect :/ (Granted, the latter could be achieved by placing text and rect in a `<g>`, but I'd still hope for the rect to somehow become a part of the text itself.) But independently of that, maybe the SVG in OpenType solution is indeed the best way to do it; maybe I can find out how to do that.

Comment: The tidy way is the glyph approach but you didn't like that. There's no other way to make the rect part of the text.